# Making car drive up a slope

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am creating a simple car game in Unity, and so far I have built the car and the enemy vehicles. I have a mountain which has a slanted road that goes up, over and down the mountain.

Unfortunately, with my code so far, my car does not successfully climb the building without either going through the mountain, or taking a really long time.

I am needing a snippet of code that allows my car to stay and travel on the ground, or to tilt the correct angle and travel up the mountain successfully.

This is my code so far:

```
var speed : float = 10.0;
var rotationSpeed : float = 100.0;
function Update () {
var translation : float = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * speed;
var rotation : float = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
translation *= Time.deltaTime;
rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
transform.Translate (0, 0, translation);
transform.Rotate (0, rotation, 0);
}
function OnTriggerExit (other : Collider) {
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Road")) {
    speed = 20;
    rotationSpeed = 200;
    }
}
function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Road")) {
    speed = 75;
    rotationspeed = 750;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `CharacterController` with `RigidBody` attached.

Answer (score 3):

Do not use `transform.Translate()` to move your car, it will not adjust to obstacles. You have to use `rigidBody.AddForce()`

You should try something along the lines of this:

```
var isGrounded : Boolean = false;

function Update () {
    if(isGrounded && !Mathf.Approximately(Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"), 0f))
        rigidBody.AddForce(transform.forward
        * Input.GetAxis ("Vertical")
        * speed
        * Time.deltaTime);
}

function OnTriggerExit (other : Collider) {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Road"))
        isGrounded = false;
}
function OnTriggerEnter (other : Collider) {
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag ("Road"))
        isGrounded = true;
}
```

Comment: I keep getting an error for the first line  "UCE0001: ';' expected. Insert a semicolon at the end."
The script isn't recognising the "bool"

Comment: The script will not work when I attach it to the car
It doesn't move at all

Comment: Your not supposed to just "attatch my script to the car" i wrote it from my head. Your supposed to learn from it and change your code accordingly. This isnt a script writing service.